# Mock or Unit testing

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, mocking, rhino-mocks

I have some question regarding mock and fake types of testing. As I am very new in this area the problem which I face is I have a method cald MarkAnalyze whose syntax is as follows.

```
public static void MarkDataAnalyzed()
{
      object uniqueId = db.ExecuteScaler("SELECT MAX(SUBSTR(UniqueID,3)) FROM History where year(date) = year(date())");
      string maxUniqueID = uniqueId == null ? "0" :  uniqueId.ToString();
      Utilities.UpdateConfig(Constants.CONFIG_LAST_UNIQUE_ID, maxUniqueID);
      Utilities.Log("Data will now be analyzed beyond Unique ID: " + maxUniqueID, LogType.Information);
}
```

Now if you see in this method then I am using db.ExecuteScaler method and passing query as an argument (I am not sure it's correct way to code.) and I don't want to change method code. Actually this code is in seperate dll. I want to test or we can say mock db object or MarkDataAnalyze method and want to control the return value of ExecuteScaler method inside MarkDataAnalyzed method. Like I want to test behavior of MarkDataAnalyzed method that how it behaves when ExecuteScaler return single value, null or anyother thing.

Hmm this is my problem. I don't know I am able to express my problem in correct way or not but trust me I tried hard to express it in these statements so that your experts could understand it.

One more thing I am using .NET Framework 3.5 and C# language as a programing tool and Visual Studio 2013 editor. So that if you suggest any library then that should be compatible with these frameworks.

Code for FoxProDb.cs file.

```
public class FoxProDB : IDatabase
{
    OdbcConnection conn = null;

    public FoxProDB()
    {            
        string InstallPath = GetInstallPath();
        conn = new OdbcConnection(@"Driver={Microsoft Visual FoxPro Driver};SourceType=DBF;SourceDB=" + InstallPath + ";");
    }

    public OdbcDataReader ExecuteReader(string sqlQuery)
    {
        if (conn.State != ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            conn.Open();
        }

        using (OdbcCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = sqlQuery;

                OdbcDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                return reader;
            }
    }

    public object ExecuteScaler(string sqlQuery)
    {
        if (conn.State != ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            conn.Open();
        }

        using (OdbcCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = sqlQuery;

                object returnVal = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                return returnVal;
            }
    }

    public int ExecuteNonQuery(string sqlQuery)
    {
        if (conn.State != ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            conn.Open();
        }

        using (OdbcCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = sqlQuery;
            int rowsModified = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            return rowsModified;
        }
    }

    public void Close()
    {
        try { 
            conn.Close(); 
        }
        catch{
            //do nothing
        }
    }

    private string GetInstallPath()
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(installPath))
        {
            throw new Exception("");
        }

        return installPath;
    }

    public void Open()
    {
        //Need to implement it latter.
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    DataTable IDatabase.ExecuteReader(string sqlQuery)
    {
        //Could be modified latter.
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    string IDatabase.ExecuteScaler(string sqlQuery)
    {
        //Could be modified latter.
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: How is `db` declared? what is its type?

Comment: db is declared in same class where executescaler method defined and in constructor of that class.

Comment: Post the code to show how you declare it and how you instantiate it. What is the datatype of `db` ? also what do you mean by *executescaler method defined and in constructor of that class* ?

Comment: I had added code for file.

Comment: Still you didn't shown what is `db` it is type of `FoxProDB`  or `IDatabase` ? if it is `IDatabase` you can mock it. Try to avoid static methods, they are hard to test. Inject the mock `IDatabase` instance to `db` and test the `MarkDataAnalyzed` method.

Comment: db is of type FoxProDb not IDatabase type.